# Mocking KafkaConsumer poll() JUnit

Tags: junit, apache-kafka, junit4, kafka-consumer-api

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to mock a `KafkaConsumer`. Below is the basic structure of my code.

```java
public void run() {
    ...
    try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(kafkaParams)) {
        consumer.subscribe(topic);
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(pollInterval));
        methodToProcessRecords();
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```java
whenCreateNewConsumer().thenReturn(mockConsumer);
when(mockConsumer.poll()).thenReturn(mockConsumerRecords);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having a hard time figuring out how to mock a KafkaConsumer

Use [`MockConsumer`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/MockConsumer.html)

---

Alternatively, it's not really clear what you are consuming from. If you want to produce and consume, use [Kafka Streams `TopologyTestDriver`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response! How do I inject `MockConsumer` to my class? It is a simple KafkaConsumer consuming data from a topic. It isn't a streams app.

Comment: It implements the Consumer interface. What is the error you are having? Note: Kafka is open source, and it has tests. You could read them... And okay, why not use streams, though? You are clearly trying to consume the data and process the records. That is a simple `foreach` call in Streams.

Answer (score 0):

First change your class (to be tested) variable type to use Consumer Interface instead of Class. instead of using [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html). use this [Consumer](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html) interface

there should not be any code change needed, just variable type change.

(same applies to producer also)

Now in your unit test class

```
private MockConsumer<String, String> mockConsumer = new MockConsumer<>(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST);
```

now you can assign the above variable to your class which you are trying to unit test

If your consumer is public, its very easy to set. If its private variable, you can use reflection

```
ToBeTested class = new ToBeTested(); 
Field field = class.getClass().getDeclaredField("privateVariableNameOfKafkaConsumer");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set("class", mockConsumer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's late for this, but could be valid for someone who is looking for this.

you should add this dependency mockito-inline
and remove -> mockito-core

```
@Test
void testSuccess(){
    try (var mocked = mockConstruction(KafkaConsumer.class, (mock, context) -> {
    doNothing().when(mock).subscribe(anyCollection());

    var partition = (new TopicPartition(“topic-name”, 0));
    when(mock.poll(any())).thenReturn(ConsumerRecords.empty());

    when(mock.partitionsFor("topic-name")).thenReturn(List.of(partition));
    when(mock.currentLag(any())).thenReturn(OptionalLong.of(10L)).thenReturn(OptionalLong.of(0L));

})) {
    when(realClass.method2()).thenReturn(60_000L).thenReturn(0L);
    realClass.method();
}
```

}